# How to upload Form data and image in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-maven-plugin, postman-collection-runner

I am unable to post File data and image in the postman and getting below exception,please advise.
Controller class:This is the post method where in requested we uploading the form data by using Multipart file to upload the image.
Exception:The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
Postman:[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHQFz.png

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Content-type and let the browser decide.